# Alarms in android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker, android-alarms

I have a date from DatePicker in
`int year; 
int month;
int day;`

and time  from TimePicker in`int hour; int minutes;`.
I need to create new alarm for this date, with notification. How I can do this?

I Have  code :

```
public void addNotify(){
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(year1, month1, day1, hour, minut);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Prmths said you probably haven't read anything on how to do that.

Have a look to the 'AlarmManager' class: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and with a bit of Google searching you should be able to achieve what you want to do.